# Doubt about definition of convergence in $L^p$.

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

I have a question concerning the definition of convergence in $L^p$.

To say $(f_i) \rightarrow f$ in $L^p$, do we need $(f_i)\subset L^p$ and $f \in L^p$?
This would allow the integral $ \int _ \Omega |f_i-f|^p d\mu$ to always be defined. However, for $ g \notin L^p$, the constant sequence $(g)$ would not converge to $g$ itself in $L^p$.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, convergence *in* a space requires the limit to be in that space.

Comment: Ok so $f$ needs to be in the space. Concerning the sequence, I guess it is not important if, for example $f_1 \notin L^p$ , and your answer implies that $f_n \in L^p$ eventually.
Do we usually avoid any ambiguity concerning the first integrals by imposing the whole sequence to be in $L^p$ or is it usually not deemed necessary?

Comment: Unless you're explicitly considering an ambient space, $L^p$ is *all there is*. That's the reason both for the requirement that $f\in L^p$ and also the reason that each $f_n$ is going to be.